# How to create database in assets folder using greendao

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, greendao

I have created the database and populate it. and put back it in the emulator. 
But problem come when I have to make the Apk. Then I realize that I have to put database in the apk and to ship with it.

So I searched for it and got the answer and that is to put the database in the assets folder. So the procedure some posts over her suggested could be applicable when i have been making my own database But I am using greendao.

So here comes the problem , So please any one know how to create or use database from the assets folder Using greendao ????

Please tell me the way How can I achieve this. Any piece of code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write to assets. Although, if you want to normally use DB from assets, you should copy database files to some normal directory like 
getCacheDir() and return DB from sqlite open helper

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to pre-populate the DB?

what seems to be the issue? you can either create a task to do after creating your `Session` Object or use the `SqliteOpenHelper` class to inject the data once the DB is created.
however, this is usually a very bad idea.

Comment: I am using greendao and that creates the database in the app directory , I need to use prepopulate the databse , and want to deliver that database with app;

Comment: so create a stask on app open to write the data

Comment: can you provide me the helping link